# How to interpret this error message from Forge Automation API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-inventor

I'm trying to execute an iLogic script in Automation API. The model is not tiny, so I'm uploading it as a single 24MB zip file. This is what my Activity looks like:

```json
{
  "commandLine": [
    "$(engine.path)\\InventorCoreConsole.exe /i \"$(args[inputFile].path)\" /s \"$(args[iLogicVb].path)\""
  ],
  "parameters": {
    "iLogicVb": {
      "verb": "get",
      "localName": "input.iLogicVb"
    },
    "outputFile": {
      "verb": "put",
      "localName": "output.pdf"
    },
    "inputFile": {
      "verb": "get",
      "zip": true
    }
  },
  "id": "<myidhere>",
  "engine": "Autodesk.Inventor+2021",
  "appbundles": [],
  "description": "Running iLogic Rule"
}
```

And this is what my Workitem looks like:

```json
{
    "activityId": "<myidhere>",
    "arguments": {
        "outputFile": {
            "verb": "put",
            "localName": "output.pdf",
            "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/...",
            "headers": {
                "Content-type": "application/octet-stream",
                "Authorization": "..."
            }
        },
        "inputFile": {
            "verb": "get",
            "pathInZip": "<assembly name>.iam",
            "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/...",
            "headers": {
                "Content-type": "application/octet-stream",
                "Authorization": "..."
            }
        },
        "iLogicVb": {
            "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/...",
            "verb": "get",
            "localName": "input.iLogicVb",
            "headers": {
                "Content-type": "application/octet-stream",
                "Authorization": "..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the iLogic code is pretty straight-forward:

```vb
Trace.WriteLine ("Starting rules")
ObjectWidth = 4 ft
ObjectHeight = 7 ft

Trace.WriteLine ("Saving PDF")
oDoc.SaveAs("output.pdf", true)
Trace.WriteLine ("Done")
```

According to the execution report, the zip file gets downloaded and unzipped successfully, but then the problem happens:

```
[07/29/2021 01:48:58] Starting work item 9b0e77a3f2d14d21b09d2eaee7652a81
[07/29/2021 01:48:58] Start download phase.
[07/29/2021 01:48:58] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/.../objects/input.iLogicVb'
[07/29/2021 01:48:58] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/.../objects/....zip'
[07/29/2021 01:48:58] '304' bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\9b0e77a3f2d14d21b09d2eaee7652a81\input.iLogicVb.
[07/29/2021 01:48:58] End downloading file from 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/.../objects/input.iLogicVb'.
[07/29/2021 01:48:59] '24085650' bytes have been written to T:\Aces\Jobs\9b0e77a3f2d14d21b09d2eaee7652a81\zip_112.zip.
[07/29/2021 01:48:59] End downloading file from 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/.../objects/....zip'.
[07/29/2021 01:49:00] T:\Aces\Jobs\9b0e77a3f2d14d21b09d2eaee7652a81\zip_112.zip has been unpacked to folder T:\Aces\Jobs\9b0e77a3f2d14d21b09d2eaee7652a81\unpack_folder_113.
[07/29/2021 01:49:00] End download phase successfully.
[07/29/2021 01:49:00] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[07/29/2021 01:49:00] Error: The 'path2' is not defined.
[07/29/2021 01:49:00] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[07/29/2021 01:49:00] Job finished with result FailedExecution
```

And this `The 'path2' is not defined` is absolutely cryptic ungooglable error. What could cause it? Maybe there's a flag that could increase the output verbosity to see more?

Answer (score 0):

"inputFile" in Activity needs "localName" property. Settings it to actual name of my zip file solved this error. Although this doesn't make the message less cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

@thesame, thanks for reporting. I think this is one bug we will fix.